# Collection not populated with Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, orm

I am having an odd error when using Fluent NHibernate.  I have an entity object called Module that is my "aggregate root" if you will.  I created and tested my mappings for the Module class and the various related classes and tried creating a Module with all of its fields filled out and saving it.  This worked correctly.

My problem is when I try to retrieve the objects from the database.  The Module object comes back just fine, however any of the collections it contains are all empty even though I see the objects in the database tables!!  I could really use a hand on this one, I hope somone can help!

*edit*: added the code for BuildDeriveModule below.

Here is my test:

```
var dei1 = BuildDeriveModule();

var sessionSource = Injector.Resolve<ISessionSource>();

using (var session = sessionSource.CreateSession())
{
    using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        session.Save(dei1);
        transaction.Commit();
    }
}

Module item = null;
using (var session = sessionSource.CreateSession())
{
   item = session
                .CreateCriteria(typeof(Module))
                .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ModuleId", dei1.ModuleId))
                .UniqueResult<Module>();

    Assert.Equal<Module>(dei1, item);
    Assert.Equal<int>(4, item.Variables.Count);
}
```

My Module class looks like this: (Note: Entity comes from FluentNHibernate.Data.Entity)

```
 public class Module : Entity, IEntity
    {
        public Module()
        {
            Variables = new HashedSet<ModuleVariable>();
        }

        public virtual string ModuleId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public virtual ISet<ModuleVariable> Variables
        {
            get; 
            set;
        }

        public virtual Variable StratumVariable
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public virtual Stratum DefaultStratum
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public virtual ISet<Stratum> OptionalStrata
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public virtual DateTime LastUpdated
        {
            get;
            set;
        } 

        #region Override Methods

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.ModuleId;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null) return false;

            var other = obj as Module;

            if (other == null) return false;

            if (other.ModuleId != this.ModuleId) return false;

            return true;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return ModuleId.GetHashCode();
        } 

        #endregion
    }
```

And my Mapping looks like this:

```
public class ModuleMap : ClassMap<Module>
{
    public ModuleMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Version(x => x.LastUpdated);
        Map(x => x.ModuleId)
            .Unique()
            .Not.Nullable();
        HasMany<ModuleVariable>(x => x.Variables)
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate();
        References<Variable>(x => x.StratumVariable)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate();
        References<Stratum>(x => x.DefaultStratum)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate();
        HasMany<Stratum>(x => x.OptionalStrata)
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate();
    }
}
```

BuildDeriveModule's code:

private Module BuildDeriveModule()
        {
            var pp01 = new Relation
            {
                RelationId = "PP01"
            };

```
        var hh01 = new Relation
        {
            RelationId = "HH01"
        };

        var stdei1 = new Variable
        {
            VariableId = "STDEI1",
            Relation = pp01
        };

        var frameId = new Variable
        {
            VariableId = "FRAME_ID",
            Relation = pp01
        };

        var persno = new Variable
        {
            VariableId = "PERSNO",
            Relation = pp01
        };

        var hp = new Driver
        {
            Name = "HP",
            Phase = 1
        };

        hp.KeyVariables.Add(frameId);
        hp.KeyVariables.Add(persno);

        var r2p1 = new Variable
        {
            VariableId = "R2P1",
            Relation = pp01
        };

        var age = new Variable
        {
            VariableId = "AGE",
            Relation = pp01
        };

        var marst = new Variable
        {
            VariableId = "MARST",
            Relation = pp01
        };

        var doctp = new Variable
        {
            VariableId = "DOCTP",
            Relation = hh01
        };

        pp01.AddVariable(stdei1);
        pp01.AddVariable(r2p1);
        pp01.AddVariable(age);
        pp01.AddVariable(marst);
        hh01.AddVariable(doctp);

        var defaultStratum = new Stratum
        {
            Number = -1,
            Driver = hp
        };

        var dei1 = new Module
        {
            ModuleId = "DEI1",
            StratumVariable = stdei1,
            DefaultStratum = defaultStratum
        };

        var mv_r2p1 = new ModuleVariable
        {
            ModuleId = dei1,
            VariableId = "R2P1",
            UploadId = r2p1,
            DownloadId = r2p1,
            HasSubunits = true
        };

        var mv_age = new ModuleVariable
        {
            ModuleId = dei1,
            VariableId = "AGE",
            UploadId = age,
            DownloadId = age,
            HasSubunits = true
        };

        var mv_marst = new ModuleVariable
        {
            ModuleId = dei1,
            VariableId = "MARST",
            UploadId = marst,
            DownloadId = marst,
            HasSubunits = true
        };

        var mv_doctp = new ModuleVariable
        {
            ModuleId = dei1,
            VariableId = "DOCTP",
            UploadId = doctp,
            DownloadId = doctp,
            HasSubunits = false
        };

        dei1.AddVariable(mv_r2p1);
        dei1.AddVariable(mv_age);
        dei1.AddVariable(mv_marst);
        dei1.AddVariable(mv_doctp);

        return dei1;
    }
```

Comment: Can you add your code for BuildDeriveModule()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I *think* I got it to work.  I removed the .Inverse() from thins line

```
HasMany<ModuleVariable>(x => x.Variables)
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate();
```

in ModuleMap and the unit test worked.  I'm not quite sure why though, so if anyone can point out that out it would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry this is so late, but for anyone coming across this the inverse property means that the child entity is responsible for maintaining it's presence in the collection.  This usually means holding a reference back to the parent.  If your domain objects weren't set up in this way, that would explain the behavior you saw.

Comment: Excellent explanation Alex, thank you.  That sums up Inverse nicely.